# Change default program for opening .vbs files

Tags: windows-7, file-association

I've accidentally changed default program to open .vbs files to Visual Studio.

Now I want to change it back to "Microsoft Windows Based Script Host", but the check box to "make it default" is disabled, how can I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this REG fix.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vbs]
@="VBSFile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell]
@="Open"

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.vbs\UserChoice]
```

Copy the above lines to Notepad, and save it with `.reg` extension. Double-click the file to apply the settings. If that doesn't help, [here](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/vbscript-files-open-with-notepad/) is a REG fix that can help.